# How to check software on STM32

Tags: stm32

I have software on STM32. I want to compare it with my source code. I need to know that the compiled code in CubeIDE is the same as on MCU.

I create a .bin file. Then I download the bin file from STM32 (CubeProgrammer) and compare it in fc.exe (Windows command line application). The file from IDE is longer. But I also checked the new software with another MCU (after programming) and there is also a difference.

Can I compare this software in a different way?

Comment: If you already spotted some difference in behavior, regardless of the method, doesn't it already answer your most important question that it's not the same? If you pulled the *.bin using cubeprogrammer, and compared it to your *.bin, that's as low level of a comparison as you can go. You compared 1s and 0s that get executed. What exactly do you mean by a different way?

Comment: Use Intel hex rather than raw binary so that location information is retained and compare with the [SRecord utility](https://srecord.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to select/click **Read all** in the *STM32CubeProgrammer*. By default, it reads (downloads) only the first 0x400 bytes from the µC, which is indicated in the *Size* box in the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

@Tagli`s answer is also right, but I'm writing this answer to approach it from a different perspective.

You can implement a counter that increases each binary change, or bugfix, release, commit and so on. So each time you create new binary you can detect easily using your CLI (if exist) or the flash sections..